# How to create hierarchial routes in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> Problem at hand

I want to create a rails app where a manager can choose an event and manage attendance for that.
I have my managers model, events model, registrations model and attendees model set up.

```
Manager (resources :m)

Events  (resources :event)

Registrations (resource :registration)

Attendees (resources :attendee)
```

where,

```
manager => has_many :events

events  => belongs_to :manager
events  => has_many :registrations
events  => has_many :attendees through: :registrations

registration => belongs_to :event
registration => belongs_to :attendee

attendee => has_many :registrations
attendee => has_many :events through: :registrations
```

What I want is to generate a URL like this

localhost:3000/m/1/event/attendance

> What I have tried

```
resources :m, :only => [:index] do
    member do
        get :event
        collection do 
          get :attendance
        end
    end
end
```

But this gives the error

```
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: can't use collection outside resource(s) scope
```

Can anyone suggest a proper way of achieving this or any alternative way which is more optimal?

Comment: you can't use collection like this.

Comment: That I realize, can you tell how can I use to achieve what I mentioned above

Comment: localhost:3000/m/1/event/attendance

Comment: What  is the relation between manager and event?

Comment: Or should I stick with localhost:3000/m/attendance and create an attendance member which recieves get requests with params as Manager.event(id).attendees.all

Comment: Added relations... please check

Answer (score 2):

> I want to create a rails app where a manager can choose an event and
>   manage attendance for that.

So an **attendance** belongs to a **particular event** and the **manager** manages it. For this, you can simply go with the below

```
resources :managers, only: [:index] do
  resources :events do
    get :attendance, on: :member
  end
end
```

This will generate `attendance_manager_event GET    /managers/:manager_id/events/:id/attendence(.:format) events#attendance`
as on of the routes which will map to `attendance` action of `events` controller.

```
#events_controller
def attendance
  #your logic
end
```

Answer (score 1):

First you may want to consider that the route `/m/1/event/attendance` is not RESTful at all. Unless you have a true one to one relation or a singleton object you should be using the plural form. `event/attendance` also lacks an identifier telling which event it works on.

You can nest routes simply by nesting `resources` (or `resource`) blocks:

```
resources :managers
  resources :events
    resources :attendances
  end
end
```

Which would give you `/managers/1/events/1/attendences`.

However a good rule of thumb is:

> Resources should never be nested more than 1 level deep. A collection
>   may need to be scoped by its parent, but a specific member can always
>   be accessed directly by an id, and shouldn’t need scoping (unless the
>   id is not unique, for some reason).
>   - [Jamis Buck](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/2/5/nesting-resources)

Which means that a better design is something along these lines:

```
resources :events
  resources :attendences
end

resources :managers
  resources :events
end
```

See also:

- [Official Rails Guides: Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)

Comment: But doing that would mean jumping to Manager controller for managing. Is it absolutely necessary to do that. Because there are more than one user types, i.e. Managers, Attendees all generated by devise. I don't want people jumping into Manage controllers maliciously even if I can restrict them by using a before_action

Comment: @Abhi9, you are thinking about it wrong. Authorization is a controller level concern in Rails. Your not going to make your application secure by making a mess of your routes - thats just security by obscurity.

Comment: I am not considering authorization, what I am saying is that, let's say I follow the approach mentioned in your answer. Then the url generated will be "localhost:3000/m/1/event" which will list Event 1. When I click on link to manage attendance for the event, what I will get is "localhost:3000/manage/1/attendance". But what I want is to keep the entire control under "m" controller, not to switch from "m" controller to "manage" controller

Comment: Your still getting everything backwards - I would suggest you read the rails guide on routing and maybe think it through a bit. Thats just a bad design.